# Through what exact mechanism is the stress energy tensor bending spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In the Einstein field equations the metric related quantities are on one side, and the stress-energy tensor on the other.

What is the deeper mechanism of how nature actually implements this interaction between stress-energy-momentum and curvature?

Not sure how to ask in a better way. Anything that exists must have some associated energy/momentum (right? matter, particles, photons, quantum mechanical wave functions, anything). So they will have some stress-energy tensor, thus bending spacetime by their mere existence. So then: why is "mere existence" bending spacetime?

Comment: Every theory is based on postulates for which no deeper mechanism is given. In general relativity, the Einstein field equation is a postulate: general relativity does not give any deeper mechanism for it. For a deeper mechanism, quantum physics seems to be essential (because quantum theory is the best foundation we have for understanding the stuff represented by the stress-energy tensor), which means that an understanding of quantum gravity is essential. That's still a work in progress AFAIK.

Comment: This is a great Feynman video giving an inspired answer to a very similar question about what is the "mechanism" behind magnet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MO0r930Sn_8 The TL;DR is the same as Chiral Anomaly's comment; at our current level of understanding, there is no deeper scientific explanation than the statement that stress-energy and the spacetime curvature are related by Einstein's equations.

Comment: I agree with the other two comments.  The question can be asked other way round: Given an exact vacuum solution for classical gravity, are there mechanisms by which we can generate non-zero Ricci curvature (matter fields)? It could be due to quantum fuzziness of space-time points( speculative ). This fuzziness will tend to blur light rays travelling through classical vacuum. This 'averaged light rays' may not even correspond to exact null rays, and so this effect must be compensated by non-zero Ricci curvature. Quantum gravity is the key...